# Not able to customize google fonts in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, fonts

I linked google fonts into my code.
and I'm not able to customize it like
`font-family:"Montserrat-Black` or thin or light as required
I tried linking the regular style and then changing it too but still isn't working.
font weights are also not working
i used bootstrap 4 also here.
my whole code is given below

HTML

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7258ec066a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand">tinDog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: white;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Thin', sans-serif;
}

.container-fluid{
  padding:3% 15%;
}

h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar{
  padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

 .navbar-brand{
   font-family:"Ubuntu";
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   font-weight: bold;
 }

 .nav-item{
   padding:0 18px;
 }

 .nav-link{
   font-family:"Montserrat-Light";
   font-size: 1.2rem;
 }
```

In this code, I've selected the montserrat-black family.
In the body `font-family:"Montserrat-Thin"` works
but in the .nav-link `font-family:"Montserrat-Light"` doesn't.
why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

The font families are not named with their weight. You have to use `font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;` for all of them and use `font-weight` declarations separately to set the weight. For example:

```css
font-family: 'Montserrat-Thin', sans-serif;
```

becomes:

```css
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
```

This is clear if you read the CSS that Google Fonts is actually giving you (by opening the link in the browser)—you can see that the `@font-face` blocks are all named "Montserrat".

(Of course you'll also need to add the 300 weight to the Google Fonts link as @Jontee said: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">` )

Comment: Also, you mentioned that "font weights are also not working" but I believe that that's because you had the wrong font name so setting the weight wouldn't change anything.

Comment: When this was applied it just applied the sans-serif font. not Montserrat, or Montserrat-Light. Was it supposed to be that way?

Comment: Well, you'll also have to modify your `link` to the Google Fonts as @Jontee said. Otherwise you won't have the 300 weight available.

Comment: If it's ok. Can I ask a doubt? how did the Montserrat-Thin work then? and if I link the Montserrat 300 then I'm not able to get the Montserrat-black

Comment: I honestly can't tell you. What I can tell you is that it's not provided anywhere within the CSS Google Fonts provides—you can [check for yourself](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;900&display=swap) (though don't be confused by the `src` declarations within the `@font-face` blocks; they're only for the name of the local resource).

Answer (score 0):

So you only imported one of the fonts. This should import both of them:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here you can select the fonts and then select embed and it will fix create the link for you.
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?preview.text=monster&preview.text_type=custom&query=montserrat&sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Montserrat:wght@300

This is what Matt was meaning.
Font weight 100 is Thin
Font weight 300 is Light
Font weight 900 is black
If you look at the link in the Html file it shows the different weights. wght@100;300;900

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

<style>
    .one{
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100
    }
    .two{
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300
    }
    .three{
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1 class="one">
        Thin
    </h1>
    <h1 class="two">
        Light
    </h1>
    <h1 class="three">
        Black
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: imported. But still no change

Comment: Sorry misread and just changed my comment that should work :)

Comment: Added an example of what Matt was talking about